# Creating an object in MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make Table1 which will have columns email, datecreated and watchlist object. I want the watchlist object to hold the columns ticker (string), stockname(string), price(float), volume(int) and column notes which will be  a long string. So I was not sure if I could have a watchlist object column in table 1 or would I have to reference another field? Should I just created two different tables: Table 1 and WatchList?

Table 1

```
Email
DateCreated
Watchlist( ticker
           StockName
           PRICE
           Volume)
```

OR

Table 1

```
Email                            
DateCreated                      
Watchlist                        
                                 
Watchlist
Ticker
StockName 
Price
Volume
```

Comment: SQL doesn't have objects.

Comment: You may: 1) expand the table and add columns 2) create additional table for object properties and refer to your table 3) use serialized representation (JSON).

Comment: Unless you're talking about using the JSON datatype. There's little value in combining columns into a single JSON object, it just makes things more complicated.

Comment: I vote for alternative 2).

Comment: Does one row may contain only one Watchlist data group? Does the same datagroup may belong to a lot of rows?

Comment: Yes, separate table is the most useful option.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a watchlist table. I wanted to try to create multiple watchlist for multiple users. So I was thinking about creating the watchlist table with a user column. so ( USER TICKER) (BOB AAPL) (BOB VZ) (BOB T) (MATT BA) (MATT FB)         So when getting bobs stocks I will get AAPL, VZ, and T and then for MATT it would be BA and FB. I do not know if this is the best way to get about this or if it is the safest. I am pretty new to SQL. This is my first time creating a bigger database.

Comment: It depends on the [relations between your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userName (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username ...,
    password_hash ...,
    ...,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    DateCreated date default current_timespamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Watchlist for each user

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userID_WatchL(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ticker varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    stockname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    price int NOT NULL, //Why ever u wanne use float!?
    volume int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Thats it. On each register you also create the second table

Comment: *On each register you also create the second table* Bad practice. Very bad. *Thats it.* And where is the relation? *price int NOT NULL, //Why ever u wanne use float!?* No. DECIMAL with correct precise.

Comment: oh yeah my bad. DECIMAL for the price. I got a old paper of mine. My examples of creating databases.\
Why is it wrong to create a new table at register. You can also do it if you add something to the watchlist, but this is the best method and, for example, to store purchases in a database.

Comment: New row (or rows) in the table - correct. New table - incorrect. DEnormalization.